# Should I do my mathematical workings out in PHP, or convert to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, math

A general coding query, really:

Once I've queried a database and pulled out my information, should I then do mathematical equations (working out percentages, different types of averages, etc.) in PHP itself, or convert my variables to JavaScript and work them there?

What advantages does each language have? If I can use PHP's `round()`, or JavaScript's `Math.round()`/`toFixed(n)`, etc., does it really matter if the outcome is the same? When would/should I use PHP, and when shouldn't I?

Answer (score 4):

For simple calculations it doesn't really matter at all.

For more complex calculations you may leverage the pros and cons of each approach. I would recommend using JavaScript because it will take the processing load off your server and into the clients. Running the calculations on the client will also allow you to offer real time customization of the data and setup nicer visualization options like graphs.

You should also consider the "JavaScript disabled" case, although this is increasingly less important. If it's not too much work a server-side fallback is always a good idea.

If your service relies on this calculations though it might be more suitable to run them on the server. If they take too long consider running them as a background process for example.

---

**tl;dr** I don't think it really matters, given the examples you have shown.

Comment: Agree, though depending on your circumstance you may wish put complex calculations on the server where performance can be managed centrally.

Comment: I'd go the php route over js mostly because of the advent of low processing powered client devices your server will have alot more calculation power than the remote devices infact it usually has more than enough spare capacity to double up your site load without worries.  Also javascript variables can be altered by client so if you're using them in say a shopping cart beware they can be adjusted to push a cart through of zero value !

Comment: The security aspect is a VERY good point. Disappointed in myself for missing that...

Comment: @Dave In most cases I would do them in php too. If it's simple things like displaying the values in a nicer way then JavaScript might be a good choice. As for security, you can never trust anything that comes from the client, it doesn't change anything calculating in JS or PHP in that sense.

Comment: @n00dle even if you perform the calculations on the client you will have to validate them on the server if they are to be stored/used somehow, so in that case he might be better off performing calculations on the server exclusively.

Comment: Its 6 of one half a dozen of another tbh :) I guess i'm just oldschool JS is for making UI elements and popups not for any form of serious work :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you will add interactivity in the future. For example, suppose you are building a mortgage calculator for a house detail page.

The database contains the home value, the down payment is assumed to be 20%, the credit score is assumed to be like 700 or whatever, etc. You can do the calculations on the server and show the results to the user.

Or:

You can do all the calculations in javascript, so you can add interactivity. The user can change some values and have instant feedback. The downside is client-side complexity.

Comment: Or you *could* calculate them on the server and use AJAX to update :) Just playing devil's advocate...

Comment: Think mobile-first. I can't assume a fast, or even consistent, connection.

Answer (score 2):

Processing the numbers in PHP means your server is taking the load for each page that's loaded, whereas by passing to Javascript, you place the load on the client's browser.

For small calculations, this shouldn't produce major differences in render time; however for larger calculations on the server you risk a PHP timeout and your page may never appear in any form. These are things you can control (increasing the timeout, upgrading the processor on your server, etc), whereas you have no control over the client's machine. For some users your result may come out almost instantly, whereas others may have to wait some seconds while their Pentium II crunches the numbers.

That said, you have to assume the user has JavaScript enabled on their browser. Whilst this is now a fairly common assumption, consider your target userbase and make sure it's a valid one in your case.

An upside of running them on the server is that you can guarantee the same answer regardless of platform. In those simple examples there you're unlikely to come across any problems, but you never know what weirdness may get implemented in a JS engine of the future. Also, for large calculations that are processor heavy, you could potentially cache the result using the server, allowing much faster results.

Basically, it's entirely dependant on the amount of data, the complexity of the calculations and the likelihood of calculations being repeated on the same data. My instinct would be to share the processing load by doing it in JS if possible, but remember to run thorough testing to make sure it's cross-browser compatible and not too heavy on older processors.

Answer (score 1):

How about having the database do it?  The database will have functions for performing calculations on the data for you also.  And it is designed for working on large data sets, so if there are a lot of calculations make the database do it.

It will all come down what will work best for your situation.  Will the user be manipulating the data requiring recalculation?  Put it on the javascript side then you save your server from having to handle the request and makes your users machine do all the math.  Is the calculation proprietary (for example, shows your markup for sales)?  Put in on the server (PHP or database) so that the user can't see the calculations.